# How do I keep commands in pages embed if I have commands as a collection?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want to keep commands into pages like 5 commands per page. I don't want to write down all the commands in embed by myself.

Does anyone have any idea how I would do this?

Comment: How have you laid out your commands? Are they in seperate files or is everything in 1 file?

Comment: @Pentium1080Ti in seperate files

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by going through your list of commands as you mentioned you have them in different files...

To get the names of all of the commands available you could do something like:

```js
for (let file of commandFiles) {
    let command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    console.log(command.name); // Print out the command name
}
```

But if you wanted to print all of your commands out, you could append all the command names to a string with a newline character in between them.

```js
let commandNames;
for (let file of commandFiles) {
    let command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    commandNames = commandNames + command.name + "\n";
}
```

Then in the embed, you could simply send `commandNames` in a field or description.

You shouldn't need to paginate the commands, unless you have a lot of them, if you do want to do this I suggest looking into the `.createReactionCollector` method on the Message object [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=createReactionCollector)